# Compactness of $\ A= \{f: f$ is power series with infinite radius of convergence and is bounded by $1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Consider the set $\ K=C[0,1]$, the set of continuous functions on $\ [0,1]$, with the supremum norm. Let 
$\ A= \{f: f$ is power series with infinite radius of convergence and is bounded by $1\}$.
I am asked to prove or disprove whether A is compact or not.

I tried noting a counterexample to show that the set isn't closed.
$$ \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^{k}x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}=\sin(x) $$

This is a power series which converges to $\sin(x)$ which isn't in the set. Does this work?

Comment: What makes you think $ \sin(x) $ isn't in the set?

Comment: Why wouldn’t sine be in that set?

Comment: Isn’t what you gave a power series? Isn’t sine bounded by $1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f_n(x) = x^n, n=1,2,\dots $ Then each $f_n\in A.$ If $A$ were compact, then some subsequence $f_{n_k}$ would converge uniformly to some $f\in A.$ This would imply $f_{n_k}\to f$ pointwise on $[0,1].$ But the full sequence $f_n,$ hence the subsequence $f_{n_k},$ converges pointwise to the function that equals $0$ on $[0,1)$ and equals $1$ at $1.$ That function isn't even in $K,$ much less $A,$ contradiction. Thus $A$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Can I say that by the Weierstrass approximation theorem  we can find a sequence of polynomials, or power series, which converges in norm to a continuous function which is not in the set A?

Comment: @GabeBoyAnalysis Yes.